# Error/Warning in netbeans on a jsp page - how to get rid of it?

Tags: jsp, netbeans

I took over a project from another coworker, and it's mostly fine, but I have one error/warning I can not get rid of:

> The attributes for a standard action or an uninterpreted tag cannot be
>   deferred expressions

Interestingly, the page works fine when deployed.

The code in question is:

```
<jsp:include page="#{appController.page}" flush="true"/>
```

I'm running it on Tomcat 6.0 and everything works, but the red warning in the Netbeans (7.0.1) editor drives me mad.

Any <strike>pointers</strike> hints for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just ignore the warning or replace `#{}` by `${}` syntax. Note that the `${}` only works whenever the `appController` is already been autocreated by another `#{}` at some point *before* that `<jsp:include>` line.

I don't use Netbeans, but in Eclipse you can configure JSF/JSP/EL validation errors/warnings. I'd start by looking around in Netbeans configuration using the keyword "validation". Using `#{}` in JSP tags was invalid before JSP 2.1, but after JSP 2.1 it is valid. Perhaps your Netbeans has to catch it up yet. Or perhaps your Netbeans project has to be configured as a JSF project instead (the `#{}` is namely usually exclusive to JSF).

Comment: That did it, thanks. It should work now: <h:panelGroup rendered="#{appController.loggedIn}">
                <jsp:include page="${appController.page}" flush="true"/>
            </h:panelGroup>